# Yukawa potential, which is correct?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conventions

Sometimes I see [Yukawa interaction term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction) written as $$-g\bar{\psi} i \gamma^5 \phi \psi$$ and other times as $$-g \bar{ \psi} \gamma_5 \psi \phi $$ Which is the correct form?

Comment: The Wiki link answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The version with the 'i' is correct. It is used in all references I checked, including  printed books from pre-web days.

The term without the 'i' may have come from some author using uncommon conventions or definitions, perhaps defining $\gamma^5 = \gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3$ instead of the widely used standard definition $\gamma^5 = i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yukawa interaction can be described by two terms, one is scalar($-g\bar{\psi}\phi\psi$) and the other is pseudo-scalar($-g\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\phi\psi$). To make Lagrangian hermitian, we have to multiply the pseudo-scalar term with $i$.